# Liberar objeto em uma função - Memory Leak

Tags: delphi, memory-leaks

estou iniciando no mundo DataSnap e me deparei com uma situação que não conseguir achar solução.

O meu código está com memory leak, pois não consigo liberar os objetos.
se eu liberar os objetos o da erro de acesso violado no result.

```
function TServerMethods1.Teste(Key: string; ID: Integer): TFDJSONDataSets;
var
  Con  : TFDConnection;
  qry  : TFDQuery;
begin

   Con:= TFDConnection.Create(nil);
   qry:= TFDQuery.Create(nil);

    try
      qry.Connection:= Con;

      qry.SQL.Text:= Format('select id, nome from clientes where id = %d', [ID]);
      qry.Open;

      Result:= TFDJSONDataSets.Create;
      TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd(Result, qry);

    finally
      FreeAndNil(qry);
      FreeAndNil(Con);
    end;
end;
```

eu preciso liberar os objetos criados  [qry, con]
porem não estou conseguindo.

Answer (score 1):

O `TFDJSONDataSets` retorna o resultado da `qry` que é passado por referência.
Logo, você não pode destrui-la enquanto o `Result` não for entregue.

Como resolver?

```
vDataSetX := TServerMethods1.Teste('stringX', integerX);
...
  usa o vDataSetX como precisar
...
vDataSetX .Close;
vDataSetX .Free;
vDataSetX  := Nil;
```

Como foi passado por referência o `Close`, `Free` vai encerrar a conexão, e o `Nil` vai liberar da memória o `vDataSetX`.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação, irei testar

Comment: Júnior Moreira,esse é o problema, pois TServerMethods1.Teste é no servidor, então eu precisaria liberar no servidor. da forma que você colocou resolve a parte do cliente, mas o servidor continua com o objeto criado

Answer (score 0):

Em se tratando de TFDQuery, prefira usar o .Release ao invés do .Free. 
O .Release chama, internamente, umas rotinas para limpeza de dados que o TFDQuery chama enquanto processa o request entre outras operações.
Se você chamar somente o .Free, pode ter vazamentos de memória.

Via de regra: Consulte se o objeto tem um método Release e o utilize. Se não tiver, utilize o .Free.